# Giving subset of equations big accolade

Tags: equations

I want to give a subset of equations, grouped together, in an `eqnarray` a big accolade to the right together with a short mathematical expression. What would be the best way to do so?

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k}x_{i - 11, k} + \dots + \sum_{k}x_{i - 2, k} &\ge& x_{i, 1}, \\
\sum_{k}x_{i - 1, k} &\le& 1 - x_{i, 1}, \\
\sum_{k}x_{i - 1, k} &\le& 1 - x_{i, 1},  \quad \quad   1 < i \le 11.
\end{eqnarray*}
```

An example of what I mean

[image]

If I should use something different to an `eqnarray` then I will do so.

Comment: You should never use `eqnarray` to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use `eqnarray`, see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

You can use the very powerful `nicematrix` package instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\begin{NiceArray}{@{} R<{{}} @{} LL}
\smash[t]{\vphantom{\bigg|}}
\sum_{k}x_{i - 11, k} + \dots + & \sum_{k}x_{i - 2, k} \ge x_{i, 1}, & \Block{2-1}{i>11} \\
\vphantom{\bigg|}
&\sum_{k}x_{i - 1, k} \le 1 - x_{i, 1}, \\
\smash[b]{\vphantom{\bigg|}}
&\sum_{k}x_{i - 1, k} \le 1 - x_{i, 1},  & 1 < i \le 11.
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix.{1-2}{2-2}\}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

The tricks are:

1. `\vphantom{\bigg|}` to ensure better spacing between rows; it's top- and bottom-smashed in the first and last;
2. `\CodeAfter` for the decoration;
3. `\Block` for the condition to be midway.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may use the `IEEEeqnarraybox` environment. See Appendix F of [this article](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) for more information about the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}
        \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[\relax][c]{rCl}
        \sum_{k}x_{i - 11, k} + \dots + \sum_{k}x_{i - 2, k} & \ge & x_{i, 1}, \\
        \sum_{k}x_{i - 1, k} & \le & 1 - x_{i, 1},\quad \quad
        \end{IEEEeqnarraybox} 
        & \Bigg\} i > 11
         \\
        \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{rCl}
        \sum_{k}x_{i - 1, k} & \le & 1 - x_{i, 1},\quad \quad
        \end{IEEEeqnarraybox} 
        & 1 < i \le 11.\\
    \end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The placement of the curly brace doesn't seem to be exactly in the center.